# Pandas returns a different word count than notepad++ and excel. Which one is correct?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, notepad++, word-count

I have a .csv file with 3 columns and 500.000+ lines.

I'm trying to get insight into this dataset by counting occurences of certain tags.
When i started i used Notepad++ count function for the tags i found and noted the results by hand. Now that i want to automate that process, i use pandas to do the same thing but the results differ quite a bit.

Results for all tags summed up are:
**Notepad++** : 91.500
**Excel** : 91.677
**Python.pandas** : 91.034

Quite a difference, and i have no clue how to explain this and how to validate which result i can trust and use.

My python code looks like this and is fully functional.

```
#CSV.READ | Delimiter: ; | Datatype: string| Using only first 3 columns
df = pd.read_csv("xxx.csv", sep=';', dtype="str")
#fills nan with "Empty" to allow indexing
df = df.fillna("Empty")

#counts and sorts occurences of object(3) category
occurences = df['object'].value_counts()


#filter Columns with "Category:"
tags_occurences = df[df['object'].str.contains("Category:")]
#displays and 
tags_occurences2 = tags_occurences['object'].value_counts()
```

Edit: Already iterated through the other columns, which result in finding another 120 tags, but there is still a discrepancy.

In Excel and Notepad I just open Ctrl+F and search for "Category:" using their count functions.

Has anyone made a similiar experience or can explain what might cause this ?
Are excel & wordpad having errors while counting ? I can't imagine pandas (being used in ML and DataScience a lot) would have such flaws.

Comment: you should try to identify the source of the discrepancy. try with a single tag first and see if it provide the same result with all three tools. depending on the settings, one tag might be interpreted as an escape character. If you noted by hand, you might have lost something.

Comment: One step ahead of you. All the tags show differences, even though they're obviuosly smaller. For one Tag it's 80, for the other 23, another one 39 and so on ...

Comment: What does your csv data look like? Could there be a difference with lower case vs upper case? What with `"SomeCategory"`? Are there spaces around the tags or around the delimiters?

Comment: surely you can isolate a chunk of your csv showing that discrepancy

Comment: @Danny_ds, it is basically Col1=Some object Col2: a property like: Title, Category, Editor, blabla, Col3: the entity like Category: Processes, Category:Questions, Josh Wilkenson and so on.
For some reason the Category Tag appears twice, once in Col2 and in Col3 thats why i search for "Category:" only instead of "Category" which would also return the results of the second column

Comment: @bobrobbob
Because it occurs on the whole dataset and it is not limited to a certain category or a chunk of data

Comment: Can "Category:" appear more than once in the same column (and only be counted once)?

Comment: Could it be there are some malformed csv lines and `read_csv()` just skips them? Do you have the same number of lines in Excel, Notepad++ and Pandas?

Comment: "Category:"can and does appear more than once the last column and it'll appear only there. 

Yes. Same amount of lines in all programms.